# How to add HtmlAgilityPack to the Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, html-agility-pack

I've downloaded the latest version of HtmlAgilityPack, where have found several folders like Net20, Net40 and etc. I created a new project and added HtmlAgilityPack via add Reference.. (I chose .dll from Net20 folder), then wrote a simple code where added `using HtmlAgilityPack;`. So now i have an error that symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration.

What's wrong? i guess that i did something wrong with the library.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

int main()
{
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    // There are various options, set as needed
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags=true;

    // filePath is a path to a file containing the html
    htmlDoc.Load(filePath);

    // Use:  htmlDoc.LoadXML(xmlString);  to load from a string

   // ParseErrors is an ArrayList containing any errors from the Load statement
   if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors!=null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count>0)
   {
       // Handle any parse errors as required

   }
   else
   {

        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

            if (bodyNode != null)
            {
                // Do something with bodyNode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to ask about non-working code that has an error, post _both_ the **code** _and_ the **error**... don't make us guess.

Comment: no, i'm not asking about the code, i'm asking how to add .dll correctly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HTML Agility pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Comment: by my question there was stated only this "In your application, add a reference to HTMLAgilityPack.dll in the HTMLAgilityPack\Debug (or Realease) \bin folder." But i did that. still the same error.

Comment: Do somebody know what to do? what program do you use to connect HTMLAgilityPack.dll to a project? I have also tried via qt creator on my mac, but still the same

Answer (score 0):

add reference by right clicking reference folder/bin in project solution